# vsoShape.connectedShapes() returns Sheet.xxx instead of Shape Name for some shapes

Tags: vba, visio

I've been working on code to identify cables in a Visio drawing based on the connector shapes that make up the cable.

My code is mostly implemented at this point. Currently it:

1. Identifies "connector" shapes in the drawing
2. Checks what other shapes they are connected with using vsoShape.connectedShapes(visConnectedShapesAllNodes, "")
3. Prints the Found Connectors (original connector shape, and linked connector shapess)
4. Runs through a series of if/elseif statements to identify cable based on the connectors found and optional user input for length (some cables use the same connectors)
5. Prints a number that identifies the cable

Successful output looks like this:

```
Found Connector: USB A - top.6
Shapes connected:
USB Micro B.113

CABLE INFO
Connector 1: USB A - top.6
Connector 2: USB Micro B.113
Connector 3: None
Cable Length: 1 m
Cable #: 812943-0010
```

This works for over 95% of my drawing. However, I am having an issue where sometimes a shape's name will be returned as "sheet.xxx" as seen below:

```
Found Connector: USB A - top.199
Shapes connected:
Sheet.211

CABLE INFO
Connector 1: USB A - top.199
Connector 2: Sheet.211
Connector 3: None
Cable Length: 0
Cable #: 



Found Connector: USB A Female
Shapes connected:

CABLE INFO
Connector 1: USB A Female
Connector 2: 
Connector 3: None
Cable Length: 0
Cable #:
```

Where it says "Sheet.211", the returned name *should* have been "USB A Female". Then, for the "USB A Female" shape, the shape connected should have been "USB A - top.199" instead of coming back blank.

I have tried re-adding the shapes to my drawing and re-connecting them with a dynamic connector but the issue persists. Has anyone else come across this? Could there be something wrong with the shapes, since they are part of a custom stencil?

Below is the code from my module:

```
Option Explicit 

Public LengthAndNum As Variant ' Retrieved from UserForm Selection
Dim foundShapes As New Collection ' The 'new' initialised the Collection
Dim foundCables() As Variant

Sub Main()
    Dim thePage As Page
    Dim connectedShapes As Collection
    Dim cableList As Variant

    Set thePage = ActiveDocument.Pages("Page-1") ' Will need to account for multi page schematics
    cableList = FindCables(thePage)

End Sub

Function FindCables(chosenPage As Page) As Variant
    Dim shapeLoopIterator As Shape
    Dim arrayLoopIterator As Long
    Dim validShapes As Variant

    Dim allShapes As Visio.Shapes
    Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim lngShapeIDs() As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intCount2 As Integer

    Dim cable As CCable


    ' validShapes is a list of all possible connector shapes for a schematic
    validShapes = Array("USB A - top", "USB A BLK", "USB A RED", "USB A - side", "USB A Female", "USB Mini B", "USB Micro B", _
    "USB C Male", "USB C Female", "Frames charger", "Lightning", "USB Surface Mount", "Sidecar", _
    "3.5mm stereo M", "3.5mm stereo F", "3.5mm stereo BLK", "3.5mm stereo RED", "3.5mm 5-pin", "3.5mm stereo right angle", _
    "3.5mm Aux", "HDMI", "VGA", "DVI", "SNF cable", "Optical plug", "Optical mini", "Ethernet", "Ethernet Female", _
    "4pin bare wire adapter", "Small 6pin power", "120/520 6pin plug", "120/520 4pin plug", "120/520 10pin plug", _
    "Maxwell 2pin plug", "AC2 plug", "2pin bare wire block", "4pin bare wire block", "SMB plug", "Coax", _
    "C13 plug - top", "C13 plug - side", "C14 'Ears' plug - top", "C7 plug", "C14/C18 plug - side", _
    "Liberator plug", "Liberator", "C14 Universal Plug Adapter", "Generic wall plug", "3pin plug male", "2pin plug male", _
    "2pin plug female", "2pin top", "4pin molded plug - side", "4pin molded plug - top", "4pin plug - female", "4pin plug - top", _
    "Barrel plug male", "Barrel plug female", "Mini barrel plug")


    For Each shapeLoopIterator In chosenPage.Shapes ' Loop through object collection
        For arrayLoopIterator = LBound(validShapes) To UBound(validShapes) ' Loop through the array
            If InStr(1, shapeLoopIterator, validShapes(arrayLoopIterator)) Then

                Set cable = New CCable ' Empty property values
                cable.Connector3() = "None" ' In case there isn't a 3rd connector - May be able to remove
                Set vsoShape = shapeLoopIterator

                Debug.Print vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Found Connector: " + CStr(vsoShape)  ' Sanity Print
                lngShapeIDs = vsoShape.connectedShapes(visConnectedShapesAllNodes, "")
                cable.Connector1() = CStr(vsoShape)
                cable.Length() = "0" ' Will need user input

                Debug.Print "Shapes connected:"
                Set allShapes = ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(1).Shapes

                intCount2 = 0
                For intCount = 0 To UBound(lngShapeIDs)
                    Debug.Print allShapes.ItemFromID(lngShapeIDs(intCount)).Name ' Sanity Print
                    If intCount2 = 0 Then
                        cable.Connector2() = allShapes.ItemFromID(lngShapeIDs(intCount)).Name
                    Else
                        cable.Connector3() = allShapes.ItemFromID(lngShapeIDs(intCount)).Name
                    End If
                    intCount2 = intCount2 + 1
                Next

                Debug.Print vbCrLf + "CABLE INFO" + vbCrLf + "Connector 1: " + cable.Connector1
                Debug.Print "Connector 2: " + cable.Connector2
                Debug.Print "Connector 3: " + cable.Connector3

                ' If there are TWO connectors
                If cable.Connector3 = "None" Then
                    ' If one connector is USB A MALE
                    If InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "USB A -") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB A Female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "831835-0010"
                            cable.Length = "3 m"

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB Mini B") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "720031-0010"
                            cable.Length = "4 ft"

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB Micro B") = 1 Then

                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm1.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "807815-0522102") Then
                                cable.Num = "807815-0522102"
                                cable.Length = "0.5 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "785495-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "785495-0010"
                                cable.Length = ".5 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "785495-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "785495-0020"
                                cable.Length = "1 mm"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "785495-0030") Then
                                cable.Num = "785495-0030"
                                cable.Length = "1.5 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "785495-0040") Then
                                cable.Num = "785495-0040"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "812943-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "812943-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "812943-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "812943-0020"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "812943-0030") Then
                                cable.Num = "812943-0030"
                                cable.Length = "0.5 m"

                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "795696-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "795696-0010"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"
                            End If


                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB C Male") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "806256-0010"
                            cable.Length = "1 m"

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB C Female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "845443-0010"
                            cable.Length = "1 ft"

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo M") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "844283-0010"
                            cable.Length = "40 in"

                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "USB A Female") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB C Male") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "835613-0010"
                            cable.Length = "4 in"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "USB Mini B") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB C Male") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "806930-0010"
                            cable.Length = "4 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "HDMI") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "HDMI") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm2.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "326853-0110") Then
                                cable.Num = "326853-0110"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "625673-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "625673-0010"
                                cable.Length = "3 ft"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "3.5mm stereo M") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo M") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm6.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "777201-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "777201-0020"
                                cable.Length = "3 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "777201-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "777201-0010"
                                cable.Length = "6 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "777201-0030") Then
                                cable.Num = "777201-0030"
                                cable.Length = "15 ft"
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo F") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "844319-0010"
                            cable.Length = "1 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "Ethernet") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Ethernet Female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "776598-0010"
                            cable.Length = "3 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "Optical plug") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Optical plug") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "629769-0010"
                            cable.Length = "2 m"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "Optical plug") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Optical mini") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm7.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806259-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "806259-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1.5 m"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806259-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "806259-0020"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "3pin plug male") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Mini barrel plug") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm8.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "727228-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "727228-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "727228-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "727228-0020"
                                cable.Length = "42 in"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "Mini barrel plug") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Barrel plug male") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "774988-0010"
                            cable.Length = "2 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "716730-0010"
                            cable.Length = "4 m"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin plug female") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "4pin plug - female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "727252-0010"
                            cable.Length = "4 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "3pin plug male") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "4pin plug - top") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "727254-0010"
                            cable.Length = "3 ft"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Barrel plug male") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm9.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "718531-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "718531-0010"
                                cable.Length = "3 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "773374-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "773374-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1.5 m"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "4pin plug - top") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Mini barrel plug") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "778056-0010"
                            cable.Length = "1 ft"
                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "815212-0010"
                            cable.Length = "18 in"
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "4pin plug - female") = 1 Then
                            cable.Num = "806251-0010"
                            cable.Length = "18 in"
                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3pin plug male") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm10.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806253-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "806253-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806253-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "806253-0020"
                                cable.Length = "3 ft"
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            ' Ask user for length of cable '
                            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            UserForm11.Show

                            If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806254-0010") Then
                                cable.Num = "806254-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1 ft"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "806254-0020") Then
                                cable.Num = "806254-0020"
                                cable.Length = "3 ft"
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "C7 plug") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "C14/C18 plug - side") = 1 Then
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                ' Ask user for length of cable '
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                UserForm12.Show

                                If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "843987-0010") Then
                                    cable.Num = "843987-0010"
                                    cable.Length = "1 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "843987-0020") Then
                                    cable.Num = "843987-0020"
                                    cable.Length = "18 in"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "843987-0030") Then
                                    cable.Num = "843987-0030"
                                    cable.Length = "2 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "843987-0040") Then
                                    cable.Num = "843987-0040"
                                    cable.Length = "3 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "843987-0050") Then
                                    cable.Num = "843987-0050"
                                    cable.Length = "54 in"
                                End If
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "C13 plug - top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "C13 plug - side") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "C14/C18 plug - side") = 1 Then
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                ' Ask user for length of cable '
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                UserForm13.Show

                                If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "844019-0010") Then
                                    cable.Num = "844019-0010"
                                    cable.Length = "1 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "844019-0020") Then
                                    cable.Num = "844019-0020"
                                    cable.Length = "18 in"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "844019-0030") Then
                                    cable.Num = "844019-0030"
                                    cable.Length = "2 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "844019-0040") Then
                                    cable.Num = "844019-0040"
                                    cable.Length = "3 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "844019-0050") Then
                                    cable.Num = "844019-0050"
                                    cable.Length = "79 in"
                                End If
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "Liberator") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "C14/C18 plug - side") = 1 Then ' BUT this fieldwas showing as blank
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                ' Ask user for length of cable '
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                UserForm14.Show

                                If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "7 IN") Then
                                    Debug.Print "7 inch CABLE - picklist"
                                    cable.Num = "7INLIBERATOR"
                                    cable.Length = "7 in"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "3 FT") Then
                                    Debug.Print "3 foot CABLE - picklist"
                                    cable.Num = "3FTLIBERATOR"
                                    cable.Length = "3 ft"
                                End If
                            End If

                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "C13 plug - top") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Generic wall plug") = 1 Then ' BUT this fieldwas showing as blank
                                cable.Num = "INLET"
                                cable.Length = "2.5 m or 4.5 m"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

                Else ' If there are THREE CONNECTORS
                    If InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "USB C Male") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB A Female") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo F") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "USB A Female") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "3.5mm stereo F") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "809528-0010"
                                cable.Length = "6 in"
                            End If
                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB A RED") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "USB A BLK") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "USB A RED") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "USB A BLK") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "831834-0010"
                                cable.Length = "2 m"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "3.5mm 5-pin") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo BLK") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "3.5mm stereo RED") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "3.5mm stereo RED") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "3.5mm stereo BLK") = 1 Then
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                ' Ask user for length of cable '
                                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                                UserForm3.Show

                                If InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "371949-0010") Then
                                    cable.Num = "371949-0010"
                                    cable.Length = "4 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "775397-0010") Then
                                    cable.Num = "775397-0010"
                                    cable.Length = "8 ft"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, LengthAndNum, "797051-0010") Then
                                    cable.Num = "797051-0010"
                                    cable.Length = "8 ft"
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "4pin plug - top") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "Mini barrel plug") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "Mini barrel plug") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin plug male") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "739259-0010"
                                cable.Length = "1 ft"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "2pin top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug female") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin plug female") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "774410-0010"
                                cable.Length = "4 ft"
                            End If
                        End If

                    ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector1, "4pin plug - female") = 1 Then
                        If InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug female") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin plug female") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "806255-0010"
                                cable.Length = "18 in"
                            End If
                        ElseIf InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "2pin top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector2, "4pin plug - top") = 1 Then
                            If InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "4pin plug - top") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin plug male") = 1 Or InStr(1, cable.Connector3, "2pin top") = 1 Then
                                cable.Num = "809521-0010"
                                cable.Length = "18 in"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                Debug.Print "Cable Length: " + cable.Length
                Debug.Print "Cable #: " + cable.Num
            End If
        Next arrayLoopIterator
    Next shapeLoopIterator


    FindCables = foundCables() ' Return found cables array
End Function
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with your code, it's best to include it in your question.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've shorted my code to fit in the question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hopefully someone can assist - I'm not familiar with VBA in Visio.

Comment: How are the shapes/connectors connected? Do you connect them from connection point to connection point? Do the CPs belong to the subshape (inside the group, not top level?).

Comment: Visio can be quite difficult to understand when it comes to determing what connects to what (and how) exactly, but there is a very firm logic behind it. Maybe you are better of using the .Connects() Property as it will directly return the connected Shapes. I had a similar Problem, expect a more through answer once I got the time to type it out.

Comment: On a more general note: you really should consider cleaning up you code a bit. extract functions, avoid deeply nested If/Else, instance a Userform instead of using the default instance, declare variable where needed.

Comment: I am using dynamic connectors from connection point to connection point. I am not certain how to know if the CPs belong to a subshape? Another person on my team custom creates these stencils, but it seems to be that the issue belongs to certain shapes (in this case, the USB A Female shape) and I'm not sure if there is a way to "fix" the shape so that the connectors are more reliable.

Comment: Yes, I am very new to VBA (this is my first project with it) so I know that my code is a bit messy. I didn't plan to post it the way it is, until code inclusion was suggested by a previous commenter.